# how to evaluate concept to false upon expression compilation error

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, static-assert

I was trying to change the following example concept code that, under certain inputs, caused an error instead of evaluating false:

```cpp
template <typename T>
constexpr bool inner = T::prop;

template <typename T>
concept outer = inner<T>;

struct pass {static constexpr bool prop = true;};
struct fail {static constexpr bool prop = false;};
struct bad_fail {static constexpr std::tuple<> prop{};};

static_assert(outer<pass>);
static_assert(not outer<fail>);
static_assert(not outer<bad_fail>);
```

This has compile error `cannot convert 'const std::tuple<>' to 'const bool'`.

I attempted to only evaluate `inner` when it would compile using a `requires` clause:

```cpp
template <typename T>
constexpr bool inner = T::prop;

template <typename T>
concept outer = []() consteval -> bool {
    if constexpr (
        requires() {{
            inner<T>
        } -> std::same_as<const bool&>;}
    ) {
        return inner<T>;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}();

struct pass {static constexpr bool prop = true;};
struct fail {static constexpr bool prop = false;};
struct bad_fail {static constexpr std::tuple<> prop{};};

static_assert(outer<pass>);
static_assert(not outer<fail>);
static_assert(not outer<bad_fail>);
```

This results in a confusing error:

`error: non-constant condition for static assertion ... static_assert(not outer<bad_fail>)`

And the same `cannot convert 'const std::tuple<>' to 'const bool'` which appears to be from the 2nd `inner`. (The compiler does not specify)

I then attempted to combine the compilation check and truth check into a `static_assert` check within a `requires` clause:

```cpp
template <typename T>
constexpr bool inner = T::prop;

template <typename T>
concept outer = requires() {{
    []() constexpr {
        static_assert(inner<T>);
    }()
} -> std::same_as<void>;};

struct pass {static constexpr bool prop = true;};
struct fail {static constexpr bool prop = false;};
struct bad_fail {static constexpr std::tuple<> prop{};};

static_assert(outer<pass>);
static_assert(not outer<fail>);
//static_assert(not outer<bad_fail>);
```

This results in a confusing error:

`error: static assertion failed ... static_assert(not outer<fail>)`

This is confusing because:

`error: static assertion failed ... static_assert(inner<T>)`

Is also thrown, implying that `static_assert` escapes `requires` clauses. Which sure enough is true:

```cpp
template <std::monostate>
concept should_false = requires() {{
    []() constexpr {
        static_assert(false);
    }()
} -> std::same_as<void>;};
```

As this has compile error `error: static assertion failed ... static_assert(false)`!

**How can I have `outer<bad_fail>` evaluate to false with no compilation errors?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `requires`-clause to initialize `inner`, which first requires that the return type of `T::prop` must be `const bool&`, then use nested `requires` with `T::prop` as its value

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
constexpr bool inner = requires { 
  {T::prop} -> std::same_as<const bool&>;
  requires T::prop;
};

template <typename T>
concept outer = inner<T>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e1jbah579)

Comment: Is `same_as<bool const&>` the right thing here?

Comment: I'm surprised that `requires {requires T::prop;};` is only valid in Clang of all compilers.

Comment: I don't think that second requires is actually needed, the first is enough

Comment: @Objectobject The second `requires` is required. The `requires`-clause only checks the *validity* of the expression, we need second `requires` to *evaluate* its value.

Comment: I believe it is better to move the solution to `outer` and present it in terms of some unchangable `inner`.